# Fire script WHILE Gravity Form is Submitting

Tags: javascript, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

When somebody presses the Submit button, I want to mark that the form is in a saving status as this form can take some time to submit and I want it to be clear to the user that it is already submitting. There's probably an easier way to do this but I've been trying to follow the documentation for [Gravity Form Javascript Hooks](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_form_saving_action_event/). They seem pretty straightforward but they don't work like I would expect and I can't find any additional documentation. Everything else I've found is about running a script AFTER submission or when the next form page loads. I need one action to fire as soon as the form begins to submit and then another action to fire if it fails.

```
// attempts to fire when submission begins
gform.addAction( 'gform_form_saving_action_save_began' , function( form, event ) {
    console.log('save_began', form, event);
    jQuery('#gform_7').addClass('saving');
}, 10, 2 );
gform.addAction( 'gform_form_saving_action_save_in_progress' , function( form, event ) {
    console.log('save_in_progress', form, event);
    jQuery('#gform_7').addClass('saving');
}, 10, 2 );

// attempts to fire when submission fails
gform.addAction( 'gform_form_saving_action_save_aborted' , function( form, event ) {
    console.log('save_aborted', form, event);
    jQuery('#gform_7').removeClass('saving');
}, 10, 2 );
gform.addAction( 'gform_form_saving_action_save_failed' , function( form, event ) {
    console.log('save_failed', form, event);
    jQuery('#gform_7').removeClass('saving');
}, 10, 2 );
gform.addAction( 'gform_form_saving_action_save_request_failed' , function( form, event ) {
    console.log('save_failed', form, event);
    jQuery('#gform_7').removeClass('saving');
}, 10, 2 );
```

When saving the form, nothing here fires. What am I missing?